# CDK Lambda and S3 artifact circular dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

If you want to run a CDK app that has an S3 bucket and Lambda function that gets its code from the bucket, you need to maintain the bucket outside of CDK because otherwise it tries to deploy the function before the artifact can be put in the bucket.

Is there something obvious I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see how it works, you can create 2 stacks and reference one S3 bucket from the other.

Sadly you can only use the IBucket object at the moment, but it'll do for me.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#sharing-buckets-between-stacks

Comment: If you are following the advice from the link: the key is to use `fromBucketAttributes()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question 100% right, but I think you can make use of the `addDependency` method. In the docs of CDK 1.55.0 I see

```
**
* Add an ordering dependency on another Construct.
* All constructs in the dependency's scope will be deployed before any
* construct in this construct's scope.
```

and if your lambda is named `fn` it should work like this

```
fn.node.addDependency(bucket)
```